# Texstudio doesn't recognize opening and closing of environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I inserted a TIZ-Environment in my document - everythings fine, no errors! Just a warning, that the environment hasn't been opened/closed:

[image]

And here's my code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1, scale=0.7, every node/.style={scale=0.7}]
        \draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 155; green, 155; blue, 155 }  ,fill opacity=0.45 ][line width=2.25]  (147,92) -- (356,92) -- (356,186.35) -- (147,186.35) -- cycle ;
    %Right Arrow [id:dp008081388677440904] 
        \draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 248; green, 231; blue, 28 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (199,14) -- (199,56) -- (209,56) -- (189,84) -- (169,56) -- (179,56) -- (179,14) -- cycle ;
        %Right Arrow [id:dp584717372432416] 
        \draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 248; green, 231; blue, 28 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (315,14) -- (315,56) -- (325,56) -- (305,84) -- (285,56) -- (295,56) -- (295,14) -- cycle ;
        %Right Arrow [id:dp8933598607947869] 
        \draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (70,130) -- (112,130) -- (112,120) -- (140,140) -- (112,160) -- (112,150) -- (70,150) -- cycle ;
        %Right Arrow [id:dp43249460780861937] 
        \draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 184; green, 233; blue, 134 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (363,129) -- (405,129) -- (405,119) -- (433,139) -- (405,159) -- (405,149) -- (363,149) -- cycle ;
        %Shape: Rectangle [id:dp02676070817238141] 
        \draw  [line width=3.75]  (5.68,-39.65) -- (514.68,-39.65) -- (514.68,210.35) -- (5.68,210.35) -- cycle ;
    
        % Text Node
        \draw (156,-24) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\normalsize] [align=left] {{\scriptsize \textbf{Steuergrößen }}};
        % Text Node
        \draw (278,-24) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]   [align=left] {{\scriptsize \textbf{Störgrößen}}};
        % Text Node
        \draw (266,224.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$$};
        % Text Node
        \draw (151,-6.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\scriptsize]  {$\{x_{1} ,\ x_{2} ,\ ...,\ x_{n}\}$};
        % Text Node
       \draw (267,-6.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\scriptsize]  {$\{v_{1} ,\ v_{2} ,\ ...,\ v_{n}\}$};
        % Text Node
        \draw (439,127) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\scriptsize] [align=left] {\textbf{Zielgrößen}};
        % Text Node
        \draw (439,137.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\scriptsize]  {$y_{1} ,\ y_{2} ,\ ...,\ y_{3}$};
        % Text Node
        \draw (13,136) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\scriptsize] [align=left] {\textbf{Eingaben}};
        % Text Node
        \draw (177,129) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\scriptsize] [align=left] {\begin{minipage}[lt]{108.95844000000001pt}\setlength\topsep{0pt}
            \begin{center}
                \textbf{Versuchsraum}\\\textbf{Ursache-/Wirkunsbez.}
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Usache-/Wirkungsbeziehungen als Black-Box-Modell}
\end{figure}
```

This results in that my whole formatting after the Tikz-Environment changes and stays the same as in the environment, which is very annoying...

Would be GREAT, if anyone could provide some help in solving this...

BR,
Mic

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please provide a complete example, also called an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), to help others to help you

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code fragment that you have posted. Either there is an error in the code that you don't show (therefore the comment by @gman), or the pretty formatting by TeXstudio got confused. In this case you maybe better report it at the TeXstudio website.

Comment: @gernot There is an error in the code. The line "\draw (266,224.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$$};"  open a math-enviroment that not been closed.

Comment: Maybe TeXstudio gets confused by `$$` in the `\draw (266,224.4)` command. Put a comment sign in front (or remove `$$`) and see whether TeXstudio is able to format the code correctly. In TeX, `$$` introduces displayed mathematics and should be paired with a second `$$`. Normally, a single `$$` gives a TeX error, but maybe `tikz` interprets it as two single `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly off-topic:

- if I insert your code fragment in simple document container:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering

% tikzpicture code

     \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It compile without any error or warning, also highlights of environments are correct (at least in WinEdt)

- however, in your code is easy to lost and make some error which very hard to find, so i suggest to consider rewrite your code in form, where you employ some TikZ libraries and define styles of image element. For example as you can see in the MWE bellow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                shapes.arrows}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
A/.style args= {#1/#2}{rotate=#1,       % for arrows
        fill=#2, draw, 
        single arrow, single arrow head extend=2mm,
        minimum height=9mm, minimum width=7mm,
        anchor=east},
A/.default = -90/yellow,                % setings default arrows arguments
box/.style = {draw, line width=1mm,     % for inner box
              font=\bfseries\small,
              text width=11em, align=flush center, inner sep=1em},
FIT/.style = {draw, line width=2mm,     % for outer box
              inner sep=2ex, fit=#1},
every label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries, inner sep=2pt,
                             align=center}
                    ]
% inner box
\node (n1)  [box] {Versuchsraum Ursache/Wirkunsbez.};
% arrows on the top
\node[A,label={[name=L1]left:Steuergrößen\\
                ${x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n}$}]    at ([xshift=-4em] n1.north) {};
\node[A,label={[name=L2]left:Störgrößen\\
                ${v_1,v_2,\dotsc,v_n}$}]    at ([xshift=+4em] n1.north) {};
% arrow on the left
\node[A=0/green,
        label={[name=L3]left:Eingaben}]     at (n1.west) {};
% arrow on the right
\node[A=180/green,
        label={[name=L4]left:Zielgrößen\\
                ${y_1,y_2,\dotsc,y_n}$}]    at (n1.east) {};
% outer box
\node[FIT=(n1) (L1) (L3) (L4)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
A/.style args= {#1/#2}{rotate=#1,       % for arrows
        fill=#2, draw,
        single arrow, single arrow head extend=2mm,
        minimum height=9mm, minimum width=7mm,
        anchor=east},
A/.default = -90/yellow,                % setings default arrows arguments
box/.style = {draw, line width=1mm,     % for inner box
              font=\bfseries\small,
              text width=7em, align=flush center, inner sep=1ex},
FIT/.style = {draw, line width=2mm,     % for outer box
              inner sep=2ex, fit=#1},
every label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize\bfseries, inner sep=2pt,
                             align=center}
                    ]
% inner box
\node (n1)  [box] {Versuchsraum Ursache/ Wirkunsbez.};
% arrows on the top
\node[A,label={[name=L1]left:Steuergrößen\\
                ${x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n}$}]    at ([xshift=-3em] n1.north) {};
\node[A,label={[name=L2]left:Störgrößen\\
                ${v_1,v_2,\dotsc,v_n}$}]    at ([xshift=+3em] n1.north) {};
% arrow on the left
\node[A=0/green,
        label={[name=L3]left:Eingaben}]     at (n1.west) {};
% arrow on the right
\node[A=180/green,
        label={[name=L4]left:Zielgrößen\\
                ${y_1,y_2,\dotsc,y_n}$}]    at (n1.east) {};
% outer box
\node[FIT=(n1) (L1) (L3) (L4)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

If you compare both suggested image code with yours, you will observe that for each images the codes are much shorter, better structured and consequently more clear (at least to my opinion) and less prone to errors.

Beside this pros, they have one cons: it can't be scaled with `scale=...` option of `tikzpicture` due to uses relative and named coordinates. In a case that you need narrower image, you need to change with of the `box` style and positions of arrow above inner box as done in code for the second image.